# No Navigation under keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, 14.04

In Ubuntu 14.04 under Gnome flashback I don't see the former Navigation menu under Keyboard under Settings.  I want to define shifts between workspaces (not CNTRL+ALT+cursor but only CNTRL+cursor), the 12 function keys to open my 12 workspaces, and to shift open windows between workspaces with CNTRL+ALT+cursor.

How do I do such now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like it with **Super + [1-6]**. In one go set it with a simple terminal command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Super>2']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-n "['<Super>n']"
```

OR with GUI App:

Install dconf-tool

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

ALT + F2, and run:

```
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" have a look there.

Look for attribute: **switch-to-workspace-[1-12]**

Set value like this:

```
['<Super>1']
```